# PySpark Dataframe show method not working properly

Tags: dataframe, hive, pyspark

I am trying to read the data from Hive table into a dataframe. While calling dataframe.show method, its throwing NullPointerException.

Did anyone face the same issue.

```
df  = hive.executeQuery("select * from test.employee")

#This line displays the numbers of records as 2
df.count()

#when i try to show the data its throwing null pointer exception.
df.show()
```

Error Logs:

> > > > df.count() 2
> > > >         df  = hive.executeQuery("select * from sbux_test.employee")
> > > >         Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/context.py", line 261,
> > > >         in signal_handler
> > > >             raise KeyboardInterrupt() KeyboardInterrupt
> > > >         df.show() 19/06/28 08:17:58 ERROR LlapBaseInputFormat: Closing connection due to error
> > > >         shadehive.org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:300)
> > > >                 at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:286)
> > > >                 at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:379)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.LlapBaseInputFormat.getSplits(LlapBaseInputFormat.java:280)
> > > >                 at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.getSplitsFactories(HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.java:176)
> > > >                 at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.createBatchDataReaderFactories(HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.java:162)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:64)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:60)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:79)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:337)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3278)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2703)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
> > > >                 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> > > >                 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> > > >                 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> > > >                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> > > >                 at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> > > >                 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> > > >                 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> > > >                 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> > > >                 at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> > > >                 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> > > >                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:478)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.getOperationNextRowSet(OperationManager.java:328)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.fetchResults(HiveSessionImpl.java:952)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.fetchResults(CLIService.java:564)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.FetchResults(ThriftCLIService.java:792)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1837)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1822)
> > > >                 at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
> > > >                 at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.security.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor.process(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:647)
> > > >                 at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
> > > >                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> > > >                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> > > >                 ... 1 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:162)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:2738)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.getResults(ReExecDriver.java:229)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:473)
> > > >                 ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFGetSplits.process(GenericUDTFGetSplits.java:225)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDTFOperator.process(UDTFOperator.java:116)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:927)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:125)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:519)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:511)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:146)
> > > >                 ... 16 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFGetSplits.getSplits(GenericUDTFGetSplits.java:498)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFGetSplits.process(GenericUDTFGetSplits.java:210)
> > > >                 ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.LlapUtil.generateClusterName(LlapUtil.java:117)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.coordinator.LlapCoordinator.getLlapSigner(LlapCoordinator.java:103)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFGetSplits.getSplits(GenericUDTFGetSplits.java:441)
> > > >                 ... 28 more 19/06/28 08:17:58 ERROR HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader: Unable to submit query to HS2 Traceback
> > > >         (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
> > > >         "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line
> > > >         350, in show
> > > >             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> > > >         line 1257, in **call**   File
> > > >         "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63,
> > > >         in deco
> > > >             return f(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
> > > >         line 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> > > >         occurred while calling o216.showString. : java.lang.RuntimeException:
> > > >         java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         shadehive.org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.createBatchDataReaderFactories(HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.java:166)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:64)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:60)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExec.inputRDDs(DataSourceV2ScanExec.scala:79)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:337)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3278)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2703)
> > > >                 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
> > > >                 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> > > >                 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> > > >                 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> > > >                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> > > >                 at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> > > >                 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> > > >                 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> > > >                 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> > > >                 at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> > > >                 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> > > >                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         shadehive.org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.getSplitsFactories(HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.java:182)
> > > >                 at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.createBatchDataReaderFactories(HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.java:162)
> > > >                 ... 34 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: shadehive.org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.LlapBaseInputFormat.getSplits(LlapBaseInputFormat.java:298)
> > > >                 at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.getSplitsFactories(HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader.java:176)
> > > >                 ... 35 more Caused by: shadehive.org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> > > >         java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:300)
> > > >                 at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:286)
> > > >                 at shadehive.org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:379)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.LlapBaseInputFormat.getSplits(LlapBaseInputFormat.java:280)
> > > >                 ... 36 more Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:478)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.getOperationNextRowSet(OperationManager.java:328)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.fetchResults(HiveSessionImpl.java:952)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.fetchResults(CLIService.java:564)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.FetchResults(ThriftCLIService.java:792)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1837)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1822)
> > > >                 at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
> > > >                 at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.security.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor.process(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:647)
> > > >                 at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
> > > >                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> > > >                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> > > >                 ... 1 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:162)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:2738)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.getResults(ReExecDriver.java:229)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:473)
> > > >                 ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException:
> > > >         java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFGetSplits.process(GenericUDTFGetSplits.java:225)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDTFOperator.process(UDTFOperator.java:116)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:927)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:125)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:519)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:511)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:146)
> > > >                 ... 16 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFGetSplits.getSplits(GenericUDTFGetSplits.java:498)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFGetSplits.process(GenericUDTFGetSplits.java:210)
> > > >                 ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.LlapUtil.generateClusterName(LlapUtil.java:117)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.coordinator.LlapCoordinator.getLlapSigner(LlapCoordinator.java:103)
> > > >                 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFGetSplits.getSplits(GenericUDTFGetSplits.java:441)
> > > >                 ... 28 more

Comment: you'll have to give more details than that. like the exact traceback, sample data etc.

Comment: `spark.read.table(tablename)` is common way to read tables in spark. and if you want to run sql, i think there is `spark.sql(query)` available.

Comment: @frederick99 i tried both the method, problem is using count() method i can see the no of records in dataframe, but on using show() method i am getting exception. not sure why.

Comment: Your traceback shows `KeyboardInterrupt()` - looks like  you did a ctrl-c